# error o confusión en construcción de sql con Query Builder Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5, laravel

tengo una consulta sql, la realizo con querybuilder, es la siguiente:

```
            $sql = DB::table('personas AS p')
                ->select('p.id','p.cedula', 'p.nombres', 'p.apellidos', 'c.nombre AS cargos', 'p.status', 'c.id AS id_cargos')
                ->join('cargos AS c', 'c.id', '=', 'p.id_cargos');
```

me dice que la columna "status" es ambigua. Esa consulta, ¿es igual a esta?

```
select p.id,p.cedula,p.nombres,p.apellidos,c.nombre AS cargos,p.status,c.id AS id_cargos from personas AS p INNER JOIN cargos AS c ON c.id=p.id_cargos
```

la tabla "cargos":

```
    Schema::create('cargos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('nombre')->unique();
        $table->boolean('status');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

la tabla "personas":

```
    Schema::create('personas', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('cedula')->unique();
        $table->string('nombres');
        $table->string('apellidos');
        $table->integer('id_cargos');
        $table->foreign('id_cargos')->references('id')->on('cargos');
        $table->boolean('status');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Comment: Prueba de cambiar el nombre, en una de las tablas, a la columna status. He tenido ese problema cuando dos tablas, en un query, tienen el mismo nombre de campo.

Comment: pero si estoy especificando con el AS a cual tabla me refiero? uff, me gusta manera todo estandarizado para las tablas! no me digan q debo cambiarle los nombra a cada uno, a mi parecer se ve feo que diga a cada tabla Tabla Cargos status_cargos.. Tabla Personas status_personas, considero que no es etico, puedo que si tengo una columna status es porque me refiero a los status de esa tabla. no se si me explique. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la unica solucion que encontre fue no obtener los datos por sus nombres, sino por su posicion.

```
                "columns": [
                    {data: 0, searchable: false, orderable: false, searchable: false, render: function( data, type, full, meta ){
                            return meta.row+1;
                        }
                    },
                    {data: 1},
                    {data: 2},
                    {data: 3},
                    {data: 4},
                    {data: 5},
                    {'defaultContent':  '<button type="button" class="editar edit-modal btn btn-info ">'+
                                            '<span class="fa fa-edit"></span> Editar'+
                                        '</button> '+
                                        '<button type="button" class="eliminar delete-modal btn btn-danger">'+
                                            '<span class="fa fa-trash"></span> Eliminar'+
                                        '</button>'
                    },
                ],
```

de esta manera no me lanza errores el sql.

Gracias de igual manera.